# Windows search is skipping folders

Tags: windows-7

I was trying to find where Electrum stored its wallet files, so I went to `C:\` and entered `wallet.dat` in the search bar (top right), which is supposed to search through the entire C drive (right?), but it didn't find anything.

Later, I manually found the `wallet.dat` file in `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Electrum_SysFiles\1.1\C_\ElectrumPY`. Searching for `wallet.dat` in `C:\` still comes up empty. Why is this?

Comment: Think you have to have "view hidden and system files" checked for them to be included in a search, might not be the cause of your problem though since you found it manually.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the suggestion, but those are already enabled ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few reasons that I can think of are as follows

Check if the file is indexed or not. Even I had this problem once and it turns out that my files were not indexed.
Try rebuilding the index. goto `Run`
type `control.exe srchadmin.dll`
Then goto `Advanced` and select `Rebuild` button.

There is also a known issue and Microsoft has a fix available at

http://support.microsoft.com/mats/windows_search/en-us

If you are not able to find any file then you should also check whether the search service is enabled.
To check on its status, go to `Control Panel` and then `System and Security`, `Administrative Tools` and `Services`

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. There is a second option that says something like "`hide protected operating system files (Recommended)`". Try to uncheck that.